# python queue vs. Queue?

Tags: python, import, queue

A lot of posts I've seen use "import queue".
But others uses "import Queue".

What is the difference between these two python imports?
Is one preferable to the other?

Comment: `Queue` is python2 and `queue` is the name of the module in python3.

Comment: python3 you import Queue from queue `from queue import Queue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue module is python 2 specific and queue module is python 3+

Importing the Queue module in python 3 will result in error

Answer (score 1):

When not sure of versions, simply add this to your code:

```
try:
    import queue
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import Queue
```